# Can machine learning be used to determine the kernel functions of a physical system?

Tags: machine-learning, function

Let's call a kernel function $K$ a function that satisfies

$$a_i = \int_0^1 K_i(t) f(t) \; \text{d}t \qquad i = 1...N$$

I have a simulation that outputs $a_i$ and $f(x)$ (and other information) based on different inputs. I want to figure out what the kernels $K_i(x)$ are from that information. Is that possible?

Comment: When you say "outputs $f(x)$" do you mean that it outputs the analytical form of $f(x)$, or do you mean that it outputs the value of the function $f$ evaluated at particular values of $x$?

Comment: Also, are your $K_i$ kernels potentially arbitrary, or are you attempting to determine them from within a particular functional family? (*e.g.* sine or gaussian, or ...)

Comment: This doesn't look well-posed to me. One solution is just $K_i(t) = \frac{a_i}{f(t)}$. I expect there are many, many others. Maybe I'm wrong, but you probably need some restrictions on the $K_i$.

Comment: $K_i = \frac{a_i}{f(t)}f_\beta(t;\alpha,\beta)$ is also a solution for any positive $\alpha, \beta$, where $f_\beta(t;\alpha,\beta)$ is a beta pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear. If you can plug in *any* functions $f(t)$, then to determine $K$ you need to evaluate it against a basis of functions. As an example, you could use Fourier series: pick $f_k(t)=e^{-2\pi i kt}$, then $K(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_ke^{2\pi i kx}$, where $a_k=\int_0^1K(t)e^{-2\pi kt}dt$. You could then approximate $K$ by just evaluating $a_k$ for say $|k|\leq 100$.